# CSS - Why is my content not scrolling?

Tags: html, css, web

**UPDATE 2** I just fixed "Edit 2" from below, where the contents of bodySection div were scrolling up over top of the navLogo/navElements divs.  Position: relative was the culprit there, and now I have no position (so, defaults to static, from what I understand) on the bodySection class, and it works as expected.

I still think some of the things within my code are a little funky (updated fiddle and code embedded below).  For instance, to have everything line up like I want it to, I have some very, very strange width properties;

left, mid, and rightSection are all set to 30% width, so they take up ~1/3 of the available space.  This makes perfect sense.

bodySection class has a width of 98%, along with 1% padding left, and 2% padding right.  Why isn't it 100% width and 1% padding on both sides?  It sits inside of the 'container' div, which is 100% width.  I figured it would inherit boundaries from the parent div.

.navElements class has a width of 95%, and if I bump it to 100%, it acts all kinds of funny, pushing text off the viewable screen.  Why is that?

.navLogo class has a width of 100%, and even the img is tagged at 100%, but I can tell you, the size you see is not 100% the actual image size.  It **IS** the size I want, but it's not 100%, why is that?

Even on a 32" monitor (my external monitor for my laptop), I see a scroll bar horizontally (across the bottom).  Obviously I don't want this.  Why is this here?

Updated Fiddle: [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hznpw2dg/2/)

Updated Code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>Frick Solutions - Technology Consulting for Small Business</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/redesign/css/fricksolutions.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  </head>
  <body id="home">
  <div class ="container">

  <div class="navLogo">
  <a href="/index.html"><img src="/redesign/img/FrickSolutionsLogoWhite.png" style="height:100%; width:AUTO%;"> </a> <!-- style="max-width:40%;max-height:3%;"></a> -->

  <div class="navElements" align="right">
  <li> <a href="/why.html">Why Us?</a></li> 
  <li> <a href="/smallbusiness.html">Small Business</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/servers.html"> Servers </a></li> 
  <li><a href="/athome.html"> @Home </a> </li> 
  <li> <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
  </div> <!--Close navLogo div -->
</div> <!--Close navElements div -->
<div class = "bodySection">
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>

<div id = "leftSection">
left text test
</div><!-- Close leftSection -->
<div id = "midSection">
mid text test
</div> <!-- Close midSection -->
<div id = "rightSection">
right text test
</div><!-- Close rightSection -->
</div> <!-- Close bodySection -->
</div> <!-- close container -->

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {

  color: black;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;  /*use this to ensure left most content goes all the way to border of page */
 }





@media screen and (min-width:30em) { /* used to be 600 px */
  .navLogo
  {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #373737;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
   }


   .navElements
   {
   padding-right: 1%;
   font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
   background-color: transparent;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 95%;
   padding-bottom: .25%;
    }

    .navElements li
    {
    color: white;
    background-color:transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
     }

     .navElements a { text-deocration: none; }
     a:link 
    {
  color: white 

  }
a:visited 
  {
  color: white 
  }
  a:hover
  {
      color: grey;      
  }


 .bodySection{
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 2%;
 padding-top: 5%;  /*this is here as a hack to make sure the bodySection div shows up under the navLogo/navElement divs*/
 width: 98%; /*
 position: relative;*/
/* overflow: hidden;*/

  }

 #leftSection, #midSection, #rightSection {
 width: 30%;
 min-width: 30%;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin-left: 10px;
 float:left; 
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 padding-top: 1%;
 padding-bottom: 1%;

 }

  .container{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/ }

 }
```

**UPDATE (minus initially updated Fiddle/Code)** Thank you all for your help already (its been less than an hour, and I've got a lot of good tips already!).  I really do love this community, even though I come here only rarely.  I will need to change that!

[This is the live version of my redesign](http://www.fricksolutions.com/redesign/index.html) -- And Edit 2, I just realized that what I've got now doesn't let me click any of the links I've put in the top nav.  I assume this is because of the bodySection overlap (with the 5% padding), but would love to hear your ideas.

As of now, I haven't implemented too many of the suggestions, but I know I will (I will just need to root through them all and probably test them all as well).  As you can see, I got the scrolling working, and have solved my 'bodySection' issues by putting top-padding of 5% on the div, so it will always drop down below the nav.  Unfortunately, this does not stop the content of the bodySection div from covering the navElements and navLogo divs once you start scrolling.

I am going to remove the code and fiddle below (to avoid confusion) and post my updated code/fiddle up here.

**Original Post (minus code and fiddle link)**

So I am relatively novice with CSS (as you may be able to discern from my css file attached in the FIDDLE), but I am working on getting better with it.  I do technology consulting professionally, and want to expand my skills/services to include web design (besides, I want my own website to be great looking, without having to pay for it!).

After a bunch of trial and error, I finally had my top nav looking the way I wanted it.

Then I started playing with the content, I wanted something like 3x2 table to display icons and text in.  I got it working (a 3x1, with just text for now) as expected, but after I did that, I decided I needed to have something between the header bar and the css table, so I figured I'd throw in a bunch of dummy text and make sure the scrolling went as expected.  What I found was that I was unable to make the body of the page scroll at all.

I have done a ton of research into trying to fix this, most posts say 'stop using fixed position' or something else to that point.  Unfortunately, if I remove my fixed position, the nav bar either breaks, or it doesn't stay visibile.

In short, this is what I'm looking for:
My nav bar needs to be on the screen 100% of the time.  I don't need any crazy jQuery to pop it to the top at a certain scroll point - I just want it to always be there.

My content needs to be below the nav bar, in a main div (bodySection).  Within that bodySection, I will need to have the ability to embed my 3x1 (or 3x2) CSS table, composed of leftSection, midSection, rightSection.

Any hints/tips/tricks to clean up my CSS and implementation of it within HTML would be greatly appreciated.  I am completely self taught (HTML and CSS - started learning HTML in the mid 90s as a pre-teen), so I expect to learn a good bit every time I interact with folks here on the forum.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick reply.

I have been toying around with that as well, but I think I may have some type of other issue, because if i put a </div> tag right before the <div class="bodySection"> (in theory, to close out the "NavElements" div), the bodySection then raise up into the header, which obviously I don't want to happen.

WHat else could it be?

Comment: Actually, on further review - there is a </div> tag at the end of the line for the NavElements div (scroll all the way right on the HTML code block on this post).  I have cleaned it up in my source, just for readability sake.

Comment: @Brian I added an answer to get you back on track, it might not be exactly what you want but at least it is a good starting point for you. If you have anymore questions, feel free to ask, we are all here to help each other out.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few things wrong (no offence, we all had to start somewhere). I'm going to post the code to fix it and write a bit of an analysis as well as some tips in a couple hours or so.

```css
body {
    color: black;
    font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    /*use this to ensure left most content goes all the way to border of page */
}
@media screen and (min-width:30em) {
    /* used to be 600 px */
    .navLogo {
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 1%;
        position: fixed;
        /* max-width: 40%; */
        background-color: #373737;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
    }
    .navElements {
        padding-right: 5%;
        font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
        background-color: transparent;
        position: fixed;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 25%;
    }
    .navElements li {
        color: white;
        background-color:transparent;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .navElements a {
        text-deocration: none;
    }
    a:link {
        color: white
    }
    a:visited {
        color: white
    }
    a:hover {
        color: grey;
    }
    #bodySection {
        padding-top: 25px;
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 2%
        width: 98%;
    }
    #leftSection, #midSection, #rightSection {
        width: 30%;
        min-width: 30%;
        height: 100px;
        /* border: 1px solid red; */
        margin-left: 10px;
        float:left;
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 1%;
        padding-top: 1%;
        padding-bottom: 1%;
    }
    #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<body id="home">
  <div class ="container">
    <div class="navLogo">
      <a href="/index.html">
        <img src="/img/FrickSolutionsLogoWhite.png" style="height:100%; width:AUTO%;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navElements" align="right">
      <li><a href="/why.html">Why Us?</a></li>
      <li><a href="/smallbusiness.html">Small Business</a></li>
      <li><a href="/servers.html"> Servers </a></li>
      <li><a href="/athome.html"> @Home </a></li> 
      <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </div>
    <div id = "bodySection">
      
      here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>
here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>here is some text <br>

      
      <div id = "leftSection">
       <p>left text test</p>
      </div><!-- Close leftSection -->
      <div id = "midSection">
       <p>mid text test</p>
      </div> <!-- Close midSection -->
      <div id = "rightSection">
        right text test
      </div><!-- Close rightSection -->
    </div> <!-- Close bodySection -->
  </div>
</body>
```

First and foremost, I suggest downloading some web development tools to help understand your issues. Personally I use chrome developer tools (comes pre-installed with chrome). Right click and inspect element to pull up a plethora of tools for web development.

I also suggest reading up on W3 Schools and their massive library of simple examples and tutorials.

Alrighty, tip time:

1. 2 body tags is not recommended.
2. ID's on body tags is not recommended.
3. Using   is not recommended, use the padding attribute instead.
4. Tab out your elements properly for organizational purposes and easy
   error spotting.

One of your bigger errors I noticed is understanding the "position" attribute options. For 99% of your page you want the default "static" positioning, this places your content relative to your other content. For navigation and objects that should stay in view regardless of scrolling use "fixed". There are very few cases that require the use of "absolute".

Now unrelated to this webpage, if you really want a nice aesthetics and don't want to spend 400 hours developing style sheets. I strongly recommend a responsive css template such as bootstrap.

For a great (I may be biased) example of front-end web development I will gladly point you to my resume website. http://www.brennen-sprimont.com/. Right click and inspect the page to get the code behind it.

**UPDATE 1**
Now for the text appearing "above" the navbar. You need to edit the z-index of either your "bodySection" to be lower or "navLabel" to be higher to get your desired result.

**UPDATE 2**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 30em)
.bodySection {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
```

Your total width was 101% before which causes a scroll bar to appear. Now of course the 3 divs are not perfectly centered, this is because you are padding left 1% in your parent (bodySection) and then have a margin-left of 10px on your leftSection div.

The reason navElements is so weird is because it is in the navLogo which has % based margins which throws you to 102%. Adding absolute ignores the parent divs margins.

Comment: that would be absolutely fantastic!  I initially started CSS just grabbing stuff from other sites, tweaking it until it did what I wanted.  This layout, I started from the ground up - and I think (as you suggested) I did a pretty good number on screwing it up.  I would greatly appreciate any inputs, fixes, and explanations, to help me keep learning!

Comment: If you have any further questions feel free to shoot me an email.

Comment: I removed the second body tag, and now only have <body id="home">.  That is left over from a legacy design I did where the active page had a different color background than the other pages in the nav.

I did remove the nbsp code - I agree its really bad, and I put padding on instead.

I am working on putting proper tabs in my code now, just to make it more readable.

When I removed postion: absolute from the navElements class in CSS, it just completely removed my <li>'s from the top bar of my page, so I had to go back to the absolute.

Comment: Bootstrap is definitely something I want to try, but wanted to learn css first.  I taught myself HTML4 when I was a pre-teen, and I love learning how these things all work.  only THEN do I use the cheat tools and templates, I guess I am just a glutton for punishment :D

Comment: You are right to use absolute in this scenario. I ended your navLogo before your navElements in my example because the naming convention didn't make the most sense to me. When I did this I also added "fixed" to navElements to make them to stay fixed. A tip I use a lot is setting various elements with the attribute "background-color: red" to understand where they are on the page if I can't see them. When you remove absolute it places the text directly under the navbar, which is white so you can't see it.

Comment: Also to fix your issue with the text appearing above your nabar, add "z-index: 1000;" to your navLogo element.

Comment: Thanks man!  I didnt realize that the padding+width (probably + margin?) had to equal out to 100%.

Any thoughts on why my divs are spaced as they are, but have widths of 100, 95, 98?  Check my latest update to the main post if you could.  You have been a huge help man!

Answer (score 0):

Your container div is labeled as a class in your HTML but you have it defined as an ID in your CSS.  Keep in mind in CSS  # is for ID  and . is for Class

The fiddle you provided doesn't load correctly, but you can make your content within your div scroll with overflow.  If you are going to keep it as a class you can try

```
.container{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Good tip - I am still learning between IDs and Classes in CSS.

I have tried using both class and ID (while properly updating the . vs # in the CSS file), but neither worked.  I also added overflow: scroll; to both the Container and the bodySection, but I am still not scrolling anywhere.  

[You can check out the live version here](http://www.fricksolutions.com/redesign/index.html)

I have put a bunch of run on text in here just to illustrate my point.

Comment: ^^ Below all the lines with "here is some text" there is a 3x1 CSS table that I made with some divs that I will use to house content.  Obviously, you cannot see them now, since I cannot scroll.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to not have 2 body tags, just as a convention. With nav elements, you can just make them `position:fixed; top:0; left:0;`. That usually is enough to make them stick to the top with few issues.

You are nesting the entire body of content inside a div with a class of nav-logo, that may cause some issues. I would just double check that you have all of your divs closed, it's easy to miss those sometimes.

also, this is kind of a loose outline of how a website can be structured, using the newer html5 syntax for things, usually I start with something similar and move up from there so I know that it is decently

`<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul><li></li></ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <article></article>
        <article></article>
        <article></article>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>`

Comment: Honestly, I think I screwed something up, somewhere.

My top nav bar is the main culprit, I would assume.  I wanted to have the Image/logo in the top left, and the links on the top right (bottom of div), like I have them now.  I had to play a bunch with positions, width, all that stuff to get the top nav as I wanted it to be.

For whatever reason, when I add additional </div> tag to close out the NavLogo div, it screws up my whole layout.  I was under the impression that I was supposed to close every div as soon as I was done using it, but again, it breaks for me for some reason.

Comment: Well with this approach you can quickly mock up something that looks okay, and that is really clean [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61q7avrL/2/)

Comment: OK.  So, I can close out the navLogo tag, and I get scrolling back.  Awesome!

But -- When I do, my bodySection starts directly at the top of the page, overlapping my navLogo div.  

We're getting there,

Comment: I spoke too soon.  Closing the navLogo div seems to have stripped my nav elements out of the top/header bar.

I do like the padding in the CSS > LI though - much cleaner than &nbsp :).

I see your fiddle, and I like it.  But, how do I get all of that on the RIGHT side of the header, and then put an image on the left side of the header?  I want them to be contained within the same element.

Comment: really easily actually. just another <li> and <img>  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61q7avrL/5/)

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.  Last part would be ... I need the LIs to be right justified.  I want image/logo (its a longer image/logo than what you used) then some 'blank space' (transparent background), then the links, which will push as far to the right as can be (aside from the 1% padding).  Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

OK consider this a freebie, you had tons of syntax errors and very difficult code to read. Remember when building your site, white space is your friend! I cleaned up your code a bit to make it easier to understand. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/61q7avrL/3/

```
  <div class ="container">

      <div class="navLogo">
          <a href="/index.html"><img src="/img/FrickSolutionsLogoWhite.png" style="height:100%; width:AUTO%;"/></a> 

      <div class="navElements" align="right">
          <li><a href="/why.html">Why Us?</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li> 
          <li><a href="/smallbusiness.html">Small Business</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li> 
          <li><a href="/servers.html"> Servers </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li> 
          <li><a href="/athome.html"> @Home </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li> 
          <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
      </div>
      </div>    
  </div>
      <div id = "bodySection">
          <div id = "leftSection">
                    left text test
          </div>
          <div id = "midSection">
                    mid text test
          </div>
          <div id = "rightSection">
                        right text test
          </div> 
       </div>
```

and your css

```
    body {
    color: black;
    font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    /*use this to ensure left most content goes all the way to border of page */
}
#container {
     width: 1200px;
     height: 1200px;
}

#bodySection {
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 2%;
        width: 98%;

}
#leftSection, #midSection, #rightSection {
        width: 30%;
        height: 400px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-left: 1%;
        float:left;
        padding: 1%;
}
.navLogo {
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 1%;
        position: fixed;
        /* max-width: 40%; */
        background-color: #373737;
        width: 100%;
        height: 8%;
}
.navElements {
        padding-right: 1%;
        font-family:"Roboto", sans-serif;
        background-color: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 95%;
        padding-bottom: .25%;
}
.navElements li {
        color: white;
        background-color:transparent;
        display: inline-block;
}
.navElements a {
        text-deocration: none;
}
a:link {
        color: white
}
a:visited {
        color: white
}
a:hover {
        color: grey;
}


@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
}
```

Comment: This looks a TON cleaner.  Did you make any 'serious' changes, or just cleaned it up?

My one concern with that is that the left mid and right sections are all semi-hidden by the nav elements.  Would that just be padding on the bodySection div?  Also, Unable to test at the moment, but will this scroll?

Comment: Yes, it does scroll. But how it scrolls might be the issue. I did not know if you wanted the nav bar to stay stationary or not. So I just made it all scrollable, and if you wanted to kepp the nav bar at the top, it is a really easy change now that the code is cleaned up.

Comment: What I would recommend, is for you to take my code. edit it as you see fit, and if you hit another problem, show your edited version of my code, while its not "all" fixed it atleast makes its easier for other people to read and increases your chances of getting better answers.

Comment: Yes, I do want the top nav bar to be 'fixed' so it is always visible.

I will certianly give your code a try, but probably won't be until tomorrow.  Wife wants to go to a winery for dinner/drinks, and I tend to not mess with my live sites after I've had some vino! :)  Thanks a lot my friend!  I will post edited code once I take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 30em)
.bodySection {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  width: 98%;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

padding left 1%, padding right 2% and width 98% so total 101% this wrong,

it need to total 100%. so just  make 98% to 97% . then scroll will go..

http://jsfiddle.net/hznpw2dg/3/ demo